# No puedo visualizar la bienvenida de Laravel 10 en servidor cpanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel

en un servidor cpanel, he almacenado mi API desarrollada con Laravel 10, desde la raíz del servidor he creado una carpeta "api_laravel" la cual contiene todos los archivos de mi API (las que se desarrollan por defecto al crear un proyecto de laravel), después, cortando los archivos almacenados en la carpeta public (.htaccess, index.php, robots.txt) los he pegado en otra carpeta dentro de public_html/test_api, y en public_html/api/index.php solo he ajustado las direcciones para que éste mismo archivo ubique a mi storage, vendor y boostrap.
De igual forma he configurado mi .env:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo debería funcionar y en cuanto agrego la siguiente url https://mi-dominio/test_api me debería de mostrar la bienvenida de Laravel, debo resaltar que mi API NO contiene vistas a excepción de la que viene por defecto, sino rutas en routes/api.php y controladores ya que cumple con el objetivo de ser una API, pero al ingresar a la url me muestra un que la página no funciona, además de imprimirme HTTP ERROR 500:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.